# Converting int to a size_t

Tags: c++, casting, initializer-list

I am wondering about the following warning of the clang compiler when I pass an `integer` to an `std::initializer_list< size_t >` :

```
non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'int' to 'unsigned long' in initializer list
```

Why can `int` be casted to a `size_t`but an `int` not be passed to an `std::initializer_list< size_t >`, i.e.

```
int main()
{
  size_t s_t = 0;
  int    i   = 0;

  std::initializer_list<size_t> i_l = { i };            // warning
  s_t = i;                                              // no warning

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The error should not be emitted be cause converting int to unsigned long is not a narrowing operation. You should contact the compiler developer and/or file a bug.

Comment: @user3528438 And what if `i` contained a negative value? As the error says, the warning can be avoided in this case by making `i` `const`

Comment: @user3528438 `int` to `unsigned long` is definitely a narrowing operation.

Comment: Note that ` s_t = i;` is **not** casting. It's **converting**. There are no casts anywhere in the code in the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have run afoul of [[dcl.init.list]/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#7)

> A narrowing conversion is an implicit conversion[...] from an integer type or unscoped enumeration type to an integer type that cannot represent all the values of the original type, except where the source is a constant expression whose value after integral promotions will fit into the target type.

Since `i` is not a constant expression this counts as a narrowing conversion and narrowing conversions are not allowed in initializer list.  If you were to use

```
std::initializer_list<std::size_t> i_l = { 0 };
```

Then it would not narrow even though `0` is an `int` since the compiler knows `0` can be represented in each type.

Answer (score 8):

From [dcl.init.list]:

> A *narrowing conversion* is an implicit conversion [...] — from an integer type or unscoped enumeration type to an integer type that cannot represent all the values of the original type, except where the source is a constant expression whose value after integral promotions will fit into the target type.

We are converting from `int` (which allows for negative values) to `size_t` (which does not), so this is a narrowing conversion. Narrowing conversions are ill-formed in list-initialization, which is what you're doing here:

```
std::initializer_list<size_t> i_l = { i };
```

However, narrowing conversions are fine elsewhere (as far as the standard is concerned):

```
s_t = i;
```

That's why the first line is ill-formed but the second is not.

Answer (score 1):

When a narrowing conversion is required while using list initialization to initialize an object, the program is ill-formed.

From the C++11 Standard (emphasis mine):

> **8.5.4 List-initialization**
>
> ...
>
> 3 List-initialization of an object or reference of type T is defined as follows:
>
> ...
>
> — Otherwise, if `T` is a class type, constructors are considered. The applicable constructors are enumerated and the best one is chosen through overload resolution (13.3, 13.3.1.7). **If a narrowing conversion (see below) is required to convert any of the arguments, the program is ill-formed.**

The use of

```
int i = 0;
size_t s = {i};
```

falls under the same clause.