# Strange behavior of narrowing in context of initializer lists

Tags: c++, initializer-list, narrowing

Does someone knows why this compiles without warnings

```
int main()
{
  const int i = 1024;
  std::initializer_list<size_t> i_l = { i }; // no warning

  return 0;
}
```

but does not

```
int main()
{
  const int i = pow(2,10);
  std::initializer_list<size_t> i_l = { i }; // warning

  return 0;
}
```

Warning:

```
non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'int' to 'unsigned long' in initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing]
      std::initializer_list<size_t> i_l = { i }; i_l = i_l; // warning
```

Comment: The warning comes from the `initializer_list`. In both cases -- with and without warning -- I pass a `const int` to the `initializer_list`.

Comment: `pow(2,10)` is not a constant expression, whereas `1024` is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting the same section as from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41248530/2069064), [dcl.init.list]:

> A narrowing conversion is an implicit conversion [...] — from an integer type or unscoped enumeration type to an integer type that cannot represent all the values of the original type, **except where the source is a constant expression whose value after integral promotions will fit into the target type**.

What counts as a constant expression? That is defined in [expr.const]:

> A conditional-expression e is a core constant expression unless the evaluation of e, following the rules of the abstract machine (1.9), would evaluate one of the following expressions: [...]
>   — an invocation of a function other than a `constexpr` constructor for a literal class, a `constexpr` function, or an implicit invocation of a trivial destructor
>   — [...]
>   — an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) unless it is applied to a non-`volatile` glvalue of integral or enumeration type that refers to a complete non-`volatile` `const` object with a preceding initialization, initialized with a constant expression
>   — [...]

So, `i` is a constant expression in `const int i = 1024;` because `i` is a non-`volatile` `const` object of integral type initialized with a constant expression (`1024`). But in the second example, `pow()` isn't a constant expression because it's an invocation of a non-`constexpr` function.

Hence, the first example doesn't count as narrowing but the second does. You can think of it as the compiler **knows** that 1024 is fine, but doesn't know that pow(2, 10) is.

Comment: Why is it only warning though? Shouldn't narrowing conversion trigger an error here?

Comment: @Ap31 Ill-formed requires a diagnostic, but the standard doesn't require what that diagnostic means. For that, there's `-Werror`.